# Is it valid to throw in a catch block (C++)?

Tags: c++, exception

I haven't done C++ in a while and my memory is fuzzy, nor have I found a definitive answer so far searching.  I'm not talking about rethrowing the caught exception, but rather catching one exception and throwing a different type, such as:

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> foo;
...
int getFoo(int id)
{
  try {
    return foo.at(id);
  }
  catch (std::out_of_range& e)
  {
    throw MyMoreDescriptiveExceptionType();
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, `throw;` without an object will rethrow the exception that was being handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely valid. It's actually quite a common thing to do. For example, a small utility class may throw a fairly generic exception. The code that was calling it may catch that exception, and wrap it in a more specific one, providing more useful information about the context. It will then throw that 'outer' exception.

The same catch-wrap-throw pattern can extended as many levels as you need, until something is able to address the problem or shutdown gracefully.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. (have to fill to reach 30 characters)

Comment: Personally, it was the second half of your answer that did it for me. +1

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Among other things, it allows you to log and re-throw exceptions properly.

Just be careful to re-throw properly. If done incorrectly, you could lose the original stack trace which makes the actual problem much harder to track down.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "re-throwing properly" part?  Would the example code in the OP cause a problem?

Comment: @Merad - At first glance, yes. The source of the resulting stack trace would be to your `throw` line rather than the line that actually caused the original exception.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and that thrown exception will be caught by the next catch in order or next upper level catch and so on